# How to map column names from df to another rapidly?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks this:

```
df

id   email   adress
1    a@a      main st
```

I have another df that looks like this:

```
df1

Id            Field
1             id
2             email 
3             address
```

How do I rename columns in df1 to the Id values in df2 so that the df1 looks like this:

```
1     2          3 
1    a@a      main st
```

I have used .map() but actually had to write the mapping myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have `rename`

```
df1.rename(columns=df2.set_index('field name').id)
Out[10]: 
   1    2       3
0  1  a@a  mainst
```

Comment: I am not getting any error message, but it is not mapping: `df3 = df.rename(columns=df1.set_index('Field').Id)`

Comment: @RustyShackleford .....you mention df1 and df2 , and name is filed name, ....please check your original df .

Comment: I got it working, had to make everything lower case.